# How to resize images for medium screen size having images for large screen size in android

Tags: android, image, screen, dimension

I've develop an app for android and now I support large screen devices. So I create an image for this device. Now I want to resize large images for medium screen sizes.

What is the proportion? For example if an image for large screen is 85x111(px), what is the dimension for medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different screen densities. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi , you have to create different images for all these densities, if you would like to support all screen.

see the links below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

hdpi ~ 240dpi - 240 pixels per inch.

mdpi ~ 160dpi - 160 pixels per inch.

so the scaling factor is 160/240 = 2/3. so if you have 85 x 111 in hdpi, for mdpi it should be 85*2/3 x 111*2/3.